# iPhone Bluetooth Access

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Is there a way to access BT functionality in iPhone, rather than public APIs? I need to do some research experiments and really don't need AppStore acception, so I can go as low level as possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible if you jailbreak your iPhone

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the GameKit API, but I am not sure what functionality you need. Could you be more specific? Do you want to interact with other IOS devices or third party devices?